# Not able to add Group by with Range in zf2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I have query which is not working its show unknown column My query in zend Framework 2

```
$select = new Select('dining_table_reservation');
        $select->columns(array('range'=>new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("CONCAT(5*floor(dining_table.SeatingCapacity/5),'-',5*floor(dining_table.SeatingCapacity/5) + 5)"),'Avgtime'=>new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('avg(timestampdiff(SECOND, '.$dtr.'.StartTime, '.$dtr.'.EndTime))')));
        $select->join($dt, "$dtr.TableId=$dt.TableId", array('SeatingCapacity'),'INNER');
        $select->group(1);
        $select->order($dt.'.SeatingCapacity');
```

my query look

```
SELECT CONCAT(5*floor(dining_table.SeatingCapacity/5),'-',5*floor(dining_table.SeatingCapacity/5) + 5) AS "range", avg(timestampdiff(SECOND, dining_table_reservation.StartTime, dining_table_reservation.EndTime)) AS "Avgtime", "dining_table"."SeatingCapacity" AS "SeatingCapacity" FROM "dining_table_reservation" INNER JOIN "dining_table" ON "dining_table_reservation"."TableId"="dining_table"."TableId" GROUP BY "1" ORDER BY "dining_table"."SeatingCapacity" ASC
```

It shows error:

> "Statement could not be executed (42S22 - 1054 - Unknown column
>   \u00271\u0027 in \u0027group statement\u0027)"

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have column 1 in table in data base, you need set exist column for group by. You can show you database structure?

Comment: If i add column name then result of query is changed. its not giving requested result.

Comment: what you whant getting from database?

Comment: Range      Avgtime        Size
0-5           1800.0000  2
5-10  2200.0000  8

Comment: If we add any column name then its not grouping given range

Comment: If i directly run query form phpmyadmin it's work properly.. but in zf2 its giving error

Comment: try (int)1 lead to the type integer
or try execute native sql query
`$select->group((int)1);`